Concentration of H2SO4 used in the preparation of phenol from cumene
My professor told that the intermediate, cumene hydroperoxide is converted to phenol by treating it with concentrated sulphuric acid, however my textbook tells me to use dilute acid.

i would suggest a better internet search in the future, it is really the first google result:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumene_process#Steps_of_the_process

yea i saw that, but i trouble understanding whether it is in the presence of dilute sulphuric acid or conc.

Well, it should be pretty concentrated - it's a rearrangement, not hydration. Good answer would need actual conc. values used in industry, which surely depend on specific process.

It's not really binary thing like textbooks would say. Too diluted wouldn't work, while adding "usual" concentrated H2SO4 could lead to bisphenol A, or other products.

@Mithoron why do rearrangements requires strong acidic conditions, are there any exceptions?

Well, here you need to actually protonate oxygen, this needs strong acid. How actually concentrated in this case, I don't know. I guess it's lower than some.

From patent US4870217A:

The cumene hydroperoxide is decomposed in the presence of a 10 to 70% aqueous sulfuric acid solution at a temperature between about 50° and 100° C. to phenol and acetone, the yields amounting to 80-90%.

So the concentration pretty much is varied.
Also see: https://patents.google.com/patent/US6225513B1/en
